# setar background color do radio button via javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou aprendendo php e tentei algo que faço em asp.net mas não está rolando.
Tenho uma página que recebe valores de uma página anterior via _GET. Nela tenho input do tipo rádio que quero, que ao clicar em um submit, o radio selecionado fique vermelho. o problema é que, ao clicar em submit, o valor recebido anteriormente se perde, então, a página não carrega. Como fazer isso sem perder o valor recebido?

a estrutura do código é:

html
head
body
form

Código php:

```
?php

define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once(__ROOT__ . '\0 -        Apresentação\Controller\PerguntaController.php');
require_once(__ROOT__ . '\0 -Apresentação\Controller\RespostaController.php');

$Disciplina=$_GET["pergunta"];
$Perguntacontroller = new PerguntaController();
$retorno = $Perguntacontroller->Carregar($Disciplina);

$Respostacontroller = new RespostaController();

$x = 0;
while ($linha1 = mysqli_fetch_array($retorno)) {
    $y=0;
    $Pergunta = $linha1["pergunta"];
    $Id[$x] = $linha1["Id"];
    $certa[$x]=$linha1["certa"];
    $retornoR = $Respostacontroller->Carregar($Id[$x]);

    echo "$Pergunta<br /><br />";

   while ($linha2 = mysqli_fetch_array($retornoR)) {
        $Resposta = $linha2["Resposta"];
        echo"<input type=\"radio\" name=$x value=$y >$Resposta <br /><br />";
        echo"<input type=\"hidden\" name=$x value=$certa[$x]>";
        $y++;
    }
    $x++;
}
?>
```

Código java script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("0");
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            $('input:radio').css('background','#000');
            console.log("Escolheu: " + radios[i].value);
        }
    }
};
</script>
<input id="submit" type="submit">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analisando o código postado, faço três considerações:

1) se não tiver tag form, pode clicar em submit a vontade que não vai pra lugar nenhum.

2) Não existe nenhum elemento com o id submit na sua página, então seu javascript nunca será executado.

3) Quando um form é enviado com submit, apenas nomes dos elementos do formulário e e seus valores são enviados, formatação css não é enviada.

Respondendo ao título "setar background color via javascript", segue um trecho de código:

```html
<input type="button" value="Me clique" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor='#ff0000'">
```

Comment: Opa. 1. Não coloquei o código html pra não ficar extenso. Possui sim um form. 2. O botão com id submit acabou ficando  no html que não postei. 3. Sobre o código do input testarei. Grato!

Comment: Tirei o form e deu tudo certo. Valeu!